# Pandas resample to return just one column after an apply as been made

Tags: python, pandas

```
def wk(args):
    return args['Open'].mean() - args['Close'].mean()

df = pd.DataFrame()

df = data.resample("2B").apply(wk)
```

I run the following code on the below dataframe:

```
             Open   High    Low  Close    Volume
Date                                            
2016-01-04  860.0  868.0  849.0  856.0  314041.0
2016-01-05  867.5  870.0  844.0  853.5  292475.0
2016-01-06  863.0  863.0  844.0  861.0  312689.0
2016-01-07  872.0  901.0  871.5  899.5  870578.0
```

which returns:

```
             Open   High    Low  Close  Volume
Date                                          
2016-01-04   9.00   9.00   9.00   9.00    9.00
2016-01-06 -12.75 -12.75 -12.75 -12.75  -12.75
```

It's clearly dubious to have fives columns with the same data. How can I make the resample and apply return just one column?

So that I may write

```
df['one column'] = data.resample("2B").apply(wk)
```

instead of

```
df = data.resample("2B").apply(wk)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Row-wise Apply and Resampler *Dispatch*

Use a row-wise [`.apply(func, axis=1)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) and turn your [resampled object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling) (returned as `pandas.tseries.resample.DatetimeIndexResampler`) back into a DataFrame with a [dispatch method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#dispatching-to-instance-methods) (sum, mean, first, last...):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2016-01-04,860.0,868.0,849.0,856.0,314041.0
2016-01-05,867.5,870.0,844.0,853.5,292475.0
2016-01-06,863.0,863.0,844.0,861.0,312689.0
2016-01-07,872.0,901.0,871.5,899.5,870578.0'''), index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

def wk(args):
    return args['Open'].mean() - args['Close'].mean()

df = data.resample('2B').mean().apply(wk, axis=1)

print df
```

---

```
Date
2016-01-04     9.00
2016-01-06   -12.75
Freq: 2B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: during so gives me a 'TypeError: wk() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis''

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly it helps to write mean after the resample? It seems wierd to be that I use mean in my function aswell outside of it and still gets the same result. Also what does axis tell the apply? Thanks alot for your help

Comment: You could also use `first()` or `last()`; I picked `mean()` out of convenience. I edited the answer to include a link to *dispatching*.  It turns the Resampler object back into a DataFrame.  The axis argument tells `apply` to apply the function on rows.

Comment: Read the links that I supplied in the answer, they should help clarify my example.

Comment: ["Any function available via dispatching can be given to the how parameter by name, including sum, mean, std, sem, max, min, median, first, last, ohlc."  ~ Time Series Pandas Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling)

Comment: @FareJump, does this makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for this technique, I have issue, when I am passing the function to the apply method, its returning the whole DataFrame as NAN values, but if I write my function as `Display(results)` and then pass this functions to the apply method then it displays all the resampling values to me, but how can I return all the values instead of the whole dataframe as NAN values?